# Open Source .Net Authentication Libraries?

Tags: .net, authentication, open-source

I'm building a website and I'd like to avoid using asp.net membership. I want to consider some alternatives before I decide to write this code from scratch. Are there any open source projects that tackle the authentication problem?

note: I need user/pass auth (can't use Open Id).

Comment: Do NOT code this from scratch.  If you can't find an open source alternative, settle for membership.

Comment: Can you give some of your reasons for that choice? I can imagine many scenarios where .net membership doesn't cut it.

Comment: There is a difference between forms authentication and .net membership. If you don't want to use .net membership, you can simply implement your own membership provider and the forms authentication will use it to authenticate and manage the logged in state of the user. If this is what you want, I don't think there are any open source solutions to this as a custom membership provider will be very specific to your product.

Comment: Well maybe not many :) but maybe mine. The DB structure is making things awkward.

Answer (score 0):

[Rhino Security](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-security) is an option and there are some articles on [how to integrate it](http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2008/10/integrate-rhino-security-with-aspnet.html) with ASP.NET MVC as well.

Comment: Rhino Security is not authentication library, is an authorization one.